# What site on Stack Exchange is best for discussing general programming language questions that may potentially be subjective / controversial?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange

Is there a site where open discussion subjective questions are accepted?

Comment: [Programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) is probably the closest, but read the [guidelines](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) closely to figure out way to ask your question in a way that stands a chance of getting meaningful answers.

Answer (score 3):

Well, first, I think this question would belong in a meta se, but also I don't think you are looking for a stack exchange at all. My impression is that the point is to ask and answer questions that a lot of people could have so that people can find those answers here. Discussion of the sort I think you are referring to I don't think really fits on any SE (At least, that is the impression I get)

You might try checking out one of the chat rooms, they are better for dicussing things.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what's being discussed. If you feel that your question meets a significant number of [the guidelines for great subjective questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/), and it's otherwise [on-topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) for the site (no career advice questions, or best coffee blend for programming, for example), then you might consider [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Walk through the [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq), and the site's front page, to get a feel for what's acceptable. Note that it's certainly possible that there's *no* appropriate site for your question on the SE network. Some discussions are better suited for more traditional forums.