# Should we clean up Meta's [programming] tags?

Tags: discussion, retag-request, meta

[programming](/questions/tagged/programming) has 16 questions. [programming-languages](/questions/tagged/programming-languages) and [computer-science](/questions/tagged/computer-science) have 9 each. [boat-programming](/questions/tagged/boat-programming) has 3. Every question with one of these tags either has no need for the tag, or needs to be nuked; examples include:

- > https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157427/what-does-expensive-code-mean [programming](/questions/tagged/programming) [computer-science](/questions/tagged/computer-science)

  **BURN IT!!!**
- > [Should these related C and C++ questions be marked as duplicates?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143845/should-these-related-c-and-c-questions-be-marked-as-duplicates) [programming-languages](/questions/tagged/programming-languages)

  Why does that need a tag to say it's about programming languages?
- > [Why was the original boat programming question deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131733/why-was-the-original-boat-programming-question-deleted) [boat-programming](/questions/tagged/boat-programming)

  A worthwhile debate, but that tag adds *nothing*.
- > [Is there any C# API available to query Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154824/is-there-any-c-api-available-to-query-stack-overflow) [programming](/questions/tagged/programming)

  Migrate to Stack Apps! Or something.
- > [What site on Stack Exchange is best for discussing general programming language questions that may potentially be subjective / controversial?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108959/what-site-on-stack-exchange-is-best-for-discussing-general-programming-language) [programming-languages](/questions/tagged/programming-languages)

  Semi-reasonable question, but again, that tag adds no information that's worth having in the tag bar.
- > [Should homework questions be moved to cs.stackexchange.com?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199320/should-homework-questions-be-moved-to-cs-stackexchange-com) [computer-science](/questions/tagged/computer-science)

  Again, there's nothing that necessitates having that tag there.

Comment: Is this also a burninate-request, or just a retag?

Comment: FWIW, the [meta-tag:computer-science] tag is meant to be a tag about Computer Science Stack Exchange. It's a very relevant tag for Stack Overflow. I've renamed it to [meta-tag:computer-science-se] and given it a tag wiki.

Comment: I object.  [boat-programming] has a critically important role here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, but must it have an *entire* *tag*?

Comment: Given that the nature of the type of questions that are *remotely* on-topic on SO has changed significantly since the era of Boat Programming, I'm not sure that it's even a valid meme any longer, no less something requiring a specific tag.

Comment: @animuson The [tag:computer-science] tag existed well before CS.SE. It's about computer science questions across the SE network. I don't see what was wrong with it and your renaming makes no sense.

Comment: Let's wait until after the split, and then yes, there's quite a bit of cleanup to do after we're sure everything we want sent back to the new meta SO arrives there.